# StackOverFlowException during Serialization

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, stack-overflow

I trying to serialize a custom type which holds a dictionary among other members. The types associated with key and value of the dictionary are interfaces which are implemented.

The dictionary looks like

```
 Dictionary<ITypeA, ITypeA> 

TypeA implements ITypeA, 
SubTypeOfA inherits from TypeA
SubTypeOfB inherits from SubTypeOfA
```

pseudo code looks something like this:

```
            List<Type> knownTypes = new List<Type>() { 
                typeof(TypeA), 
                typeof(SubTypeOfA),
                typeof(SubTypeOfB)
            };

DataContractSerializer serializer =
                new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataHolder), knownTypes);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(completeFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(fs, templateData);
                success = true;
            }
```

I get a StackOverflowException when WriteObject() is getting called, am clueless on what is causing that to happen.

All the classes in the hierarchy are decorated with [DataContract] and the members to be serialized are decoreated with [DataMember].

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get this exception the first time its called?

Comment: What is `DataHolder`? What is `templateData`? And what do the other types consist of, other than their inheritance?

Comment: Also, what is the message of the `StackOverflowException`? Does it give you any clues as to what went wrong?

Comment: The exception is thrown everytime. TemplateData is a custom type which has the data to be to serialized, it contains a dictionary among other objects. The message itself doesnt say anything useful, and you cant even get a stack trace for StackOverflowException, as the system is not in a stable state at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might expect something like this if you have a cycle in the graph, but which is somehow **not** detected as an object identity failure. By cyclic, I mean:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract] class Foo {
    public Foo() { Bar = this; }
    [DataMember] public Foo Bar { get; set; }
    static void Main() {
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Foo)).WriteObject(
            System.IO.Stream.Null, new Foo());
    }
}
```

which throws the error:

> Object graph for type 'Foo' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.

This is because it is trying to walk the tree (not a graph), and noticing a repeat (identical object reference), and stopping. However, by testing the above (and seeing when the `get` is called), it looks like DCS actually does this by spotting pain - the depth before it aborts is very high.

Locally, I get 528 calls to `Bar` before it dies. If you already have complex code *above* this in the stack, it could account for a stack overflow, for sure.

Comment: (for comparison, in my own serializer I start checking for cycles after about depth 10? 50? Something like that)

Comment: Marc -  You were bang on target. One of the properties in the class was calling a constructor, which caused this whole recursive loop, causing the exception. Thanks a lot for the help..